# A proper way to separate concerns?

Tags: ember.js

My app allows the users to manage their documents. When creating one, a user has to either enter the document content manually or select a file from their computer (which would convert many formats to HTML for the user).

Currently, I have a simple `FileUploaderView` which is basically an `<input type="file">` that listens to file changes, and updates the `value` property of the view with an object like `{ file: { type: SOME_TYPE' }, content: SOME_CONTENT }`.

Then, `DocumentsNewController` listens to changes in it and converts supported files to HTML, and puts the result into the document body.

However, doing it this way feels simply wrong and does not allow for simple reuse (which I want to be able to do).

```
App.DocumentsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
   # ... stuff ...

  handleDocumentUpload: (->
    doc = @get 'documentUpload'
    return unless doc

    Ember.run =>
      @set 'uploadError', false
      @set 'unsupportedFile', false
      @set 'processingUpload', true

    type = doc.file.type
    text = ''

    try
      if type.match /^text\//
        text = doc.content
        # Convert new lines to br's and paragraphs
        text = '<p>' + text.replace(/\n([ \t]*\n)+/g, '</p><p>').replace('\n', '<br />') + '</p>'
      else if type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
        text = new DOCX2HTML(doc.content).convert()
      else
        @set 'unsupportedFile', true
    catch error
      @set 'uploadError', true
    finally
      @set 'text', text
      Ember.run => @set 'processingUpload', false
  ).observes 'documentUpload'
```

And the template is something like

```
... stuff ...

{{view App.FileUploaderView valueBinding="documentUpload" accept="text/*"}}
```

What would be the proper way to refactor file converting stuff out of the controller?

I want to be able to do something like:

```
{{documentHandler resultBinding="documentUpload"}}
```

and in controller

```
App.DocumentsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  # ... stuff ...

  handleDocumentUpload: (->
    if doc = @get 'documentUpload'
      @set 'text', doc
  ).observes 'documentUpload'
```

My first thought was to make a `DocumentHandlerView` which would display the input field, show the spinner, show the errors, parse the document and assign the result to `result` (and since controller's template has `resultBinding="documentUpload"`, the HTML would trigger the controller's observer).

Using a view for that would allow for easier reuse but I still feel it's not the view's job to parse the document.

Is there a better way?

Comment: having logic in your controller seams the correct place so far

Comment: But I want to be able to reuse it in other controllers. It would be too weird to duplicate it in every controller that I need to do document handling.

Comment: you can create a controller mixin from which you then extend your controllers from

Answer (score 0):

After reading closely your question the best thing that comes in mind would be to create a `Ember.Mixin` and then use it for all the controllers that need the same functionality.

Example taken from the ember [API docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html):

```
App.Editable = Ember.Mixin.create({
  edit: function() {
    console.log('starting to edit');
    this.set('isEditing', true);
  },
  isEditing: false
});

// Mix mixins into classes by passing them as the first arguments to
// .extend.
App.CommentView = Ember.View.extend(App.Editable, {
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{#if isEditing}}...{{else}}...{{/if}}')
});

commentView = App.CommentView.create();
commentView.edit(); // outputs 'starting to edit'
```

The example is only conceptual, but it will be easy to create a `mixin` yourself and put all the common logic in there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I have thought of it — it's a nice way to share some behavior between controllers. I'm not completely sure that processing the document upload is the job of this controller in the first place though. Maybe a control is a way to go?