# Pass a preset into a create controller

Tags: ember.js

In my app, there are Templates and Documents. I want to be able to create a document from a template, i.e. the user will be able to go to the template show page, click a button, and be redirected to the new document page, with document text pre-filled from the template (I only need to have the text pre-filled, I don't care about the document knowing the template it's made from).

But how would I pass the text to the new document page?

Comment: it would be easier to help if you would show some code of what you have tried so far

Comment: I am just stuck. I have one idea of how to possibly implement it, but it's awful. Basically, I'd create a separate /new route that accepts template id, and a separate controller which does everything that "normal" NewController does, but also copies text from template. I think it's too weird to even consider it, and I can't seem to think of any other options.

Comment: have a look at my answer to your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496726/a-proper-way-to-separate-concerns/17497890#17497890) I guess it applies also for this question

Comment: How does this relate to mixins?

Comment: you are right, it does not, I was to rapid on commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'documents', ->
    @route 'new'
    @route 'new_from_template', path: '/new/:template_id'

App.DocumentsNewFromTemplateRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    model = App.Document.createRecord()

    if params.template_id
      App.Template.find(params.template_id).then (template) ->
        model.set 'text', template.get('text')

    model

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    if model._reference.type == App.Template
      model = @model(template_id: model.id)

    @currentModel = model
    @controllerFor('documentsNew').set 'model', model

  renderTemplate: ->
    @render 'documents/new'
```

And to link to new document form for template, I simply do

```
{{#linkTo 'documents.new_from_template' template}}Create a document{{/linkTo}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an action in the controller:

```
App.TemplateRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Em.Object.create({
      name: "A Template",
      values: {title: "Templated Title"}
    });
  }
});

App.TemplateController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  goToNewDocument: function() {
    var o = Em.Object.create(this.get('values'));
    o.set('source', 'Template');
    App.Router.router.transitionTo('newdoc', o);
  }
});

App.NewdocRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Em.Object.create({title: "Default Title", source: "Model hook"});
  }
});
```

[jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/eqezaq/1/)